# CGI error while trying to retrieve from sqlite3

Tags: ubuntu, python, sqlite, cgi

I am trying to build a very simple login page, which asks the user for his `register_no`, `username` and `password`. And when he presses the submit button. I am trying to check whether it is an existing user or a new user and display a message accordingly.

My folder hierarchy is like this

```
prodicus@Acer:~/Downloads/souvik_refactoring$ tree
.
├── cgi-bin
│   ├── creating_user_base_table.py
│   ├── user_base.db
│   └── usr_check.py
├── index.html
└── keyCheck.py

1 directory, 5 files
```

**What I have tried:**

For the `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style = "text-align : center ; ">
        <h1>Login page</h1>
        <form action="/cgi-bin/usr_check.py" method="get"> 
            Registration number : <input type="number" name="register_no" min="1" max="2000000000">
            <br><br>
            Username : <input type="text" name="username">
            <br><br>
            Password : <input type="password" name = "password">
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value = "Login">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

For `creating_user_base_table.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4

import sqlite3
import os

db_name = "user_base.db"

if db_name in os.listdir():
    print("removing the user_base.db and creating a fresh copy of it")
    os.system("rm user_base.db")

print("Creating the database")
conn = sqlite3.connect(db_name)
cur = conn.cursor()

user_table = "CREATE TABLE users(reg_no INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, user_name TEXT, pass TEXT)"

new_users = (
    (1081310251, 'admin', 'admin'),
    (1081310234, 'foo', 'admin123')
)

cur.execute(user_table)
print("table created")
cur.executemany('INSERT INTO users VALUES(?, ?, ?)', new_users)
conn.commit()
print("default users created \n\ndisplaying them")

cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users')
print(cur.fetchall())
```

and finally `usr_check.py`

```
#/usr/bin/env python3.4

import cgi, cgitb
import os
import sqlite3

cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
register_no = form.getvalue('register_no')
username = form.getvalue('username')
passwd = form.getvalue('password')

print("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
print("<html>")
print("<head>")
print("<h1>Shit gets real here</h1>")
print("</head>")
print("<body>")
print('<div style = "text-align:center ; "')
# print("</div>")
print("")

conn = sqlite3.connect('user_base.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

## now to check whether the entered data is for
## -> new user 
## -> an old user

cur.execute('SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE register_no = ?', (register_no,))
rows = cur.fetchall()
print("<br><br>")
if len(rows) == 0:  
    print("<p>User : <b>", username , "</b> does not exist.</p>")
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO users VALUES(?, ?, ?)', (register_no, username, passwd))
    print("<p>User was created successfully</p>")
    print("Done")

else:
    print("<p>Welcome<b>", username ,"</b>. Good to have you back")
    print("<br><p>Your account details</p>")
    print("<ul>")
    print("<li>Register number : ", register_no, " </li>")
    print("<li>Username " , username, "</li>")
    print("</ul>")
```

**Error log** :

```
prodicus@Acer:~/Downloads/souvik_refactoring$ python -m CGIHTTPServer
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Nov/2015 12:43:23] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Nov/2015 12:44:03] "GET /cgi-bin/usr_check.py?register_no=1081310234&username=foo&password=admin123 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/CGIHTTPServer.py", line 252, in run_cgi
    os.execve(scriptfile, args, env)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Nov/2015 12:44:03] CGI script exit status 0x7f00
```

Following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793042/sqlite3-insert-using-python-and-python-cgi I have the files permissions

```
prodicus@Acer:~/Downloads/souvik_refactoring$ ll
total 36
drwxrwxr-x  3 prodicus prodicus  4096 Nov  2 08:30 ./
drwxr-xr-x 15 prodicus prodicus 20480 Nov  2 11:29 ../
drwxrwxrwx  2 prodicus prodicus  4096 Nov  2 12:23 cgi-bin/
-rw-rw-r--  1 prodicus prodicus   629 Nov  2 08:38 index.html
-rwxrwxr-x  1 prodicus prodicus   463 Nov  2 08:29 keyCheck.py*
```

and

```
prodicus@Acer:~/Downloads/souvik_refactoring/cgi-bin$ ll
total 20
drwxrwxrwx 2 prodicus prodicus 4096 Nov  2 12:23 ./
drwxrwxr-x 3 prodicus prodicus 4096 Nov  2 08:30 ../
-rwxrwxrwx 1 prodicus prodicus  710 Nov  1 23:12 creating_user_base_table.py*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 prodicus prodicus 2048 Nov  2 12:23 user_base.db*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 prodicus prodicus 1576 Nov  2 08:26 usr_check.py*
```

Surprisingly, `cgitb` is not showing an error. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: is `python3.4` in your web-server's PATH?  use the full path to your python3.4 interpreter on the `#!` line instead.

Comment: is your web server configured to use fastcgi or something to handle `*.py` files differently?  because that error message indicates it's running your script with python2.7

Comment: @cas : I did a `sys.path` in the `python3.4` interpreter and it showed `'/usr/lib/python3.4'` and some others. I think it means I have it in my `PATH` right

Comment: @cas : I am not sure about that, I was trying to test this with the `CGIHTTPServer` which comes with `python`. Any help on that?

Comment: did you edit those python scripts on a windows machine? do they have CR-LF line-endings rather than just LF?   show output of `sed -n 1l usr_check.py` (that's a `1` and a lower-case `l` for the sed script)

Comment: sorry, i know nothing about CGIHTTPServer

Comment: @cas : I get `#/usr/bin/env python3.4$` as the output for the sed script. What does that mean ?

Comment: it means the file wasn't edited on a windows box (or has had the line-endings converted from windows `\r\n` to `\n` unix style).  so we're back to "is python3.4 in your web server's PATH".  try running a simple sh CGI script that dumps env as text/plain, and examine the PATH variable.   `#!/bin/sh
printf "%s\n\n" "Content-Type: text/plain" ; env` (the space after /bin/sh is actually a linefeed)

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured out what was wrong with this. Was making a really silly mistake! Thanks to @cas for making me come to it.

Had done a `#/usr/bin/env python3.4` instead of `#!/usr/bin/env python3.4`.

Second being, I had to give the absolute path when the script `usr_check.py` was trying to connect to the database `user_base.db`.

That solved the problem for me.

Comment: should have spotted it myself...didn't even look at the `#!` lines after the first one.